# Codeigniter App works in one subdomain, but not in another. Why?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I have a Codeigniter 3 application. I have set the base_url correctly in this format: http://subdomain.domain.com/.

I uploaded it application to a subdomain we have configured through AWS, and I get a "404 URL not found on this server" when attempting to access my login controller method at this url: subdomain.domain.com/users/login. I thought this was strange because I think my htaccess file is correct and looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

My class name is capitalized as it should be, as Users, and the file name is capitalized as well: Users.php.

Suspicious, I uploaded the app folder to a completely different subdomain, a personal one, that is hosted through Bluehost, changed the base_url accordingly, and everything works fine. No 404s or anything.

I've spent a ton of time digging around stackoverflow, and while I see some questions and answers that have suggested fixes, I have followed those and have not fixed my problem, leading me to believe it could be an issue with how our AWS box is set up. It's on ubuntu 14.04, and I created a subdomain.conf as part of the process in creating the subdomain. We have the domain for that through GoDaddy, where I added an A HOST for the subdomain.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: see if a plain html file works on the subdomain to verify whether its working at all.

Comment: What is an error? Check the apache logs too.

Comment: @cartalot plain html file works. The default route to my controller method that loads index.php works as well. It's only when I try to navigate away using other controller methods, or URLs that point to those methods.

Checked the logs and couldn't find anything. All I see is the 404 URL not found on this server. 

I noticed my .conf file didn't have the right path, so I fixed that, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem. I ended up going into our apache2.conf file on and changing this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
```

```
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
```

To this:

```
AllowOverride All
```

On all directories.

Changing AllowOverride from None to All relaxes the access on the document root. If you're using linux, remember to restart Apache with sudo service apache2 restart.